# How can I create an android activity with back arrow as shown in the picture

Tags: android

[image: activity actionbar with back arrow similar to android material design menu]

activity actionbar with back arrow similar to android material design menu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add the following to your `activity` tag inside your `manifest.xml` file:

```
android:parentActivityName=".screens.MainActivity"
```

This will automatically place a back arrow inside your `Activity` and navigate to `MainActivity` when pressed.

**Note** This will only work in Android 4.1 or greater:

> Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName attribute in the  element.

If your app targets Android 4.0 or before you should include the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) and add the following to your `activity` inside the `manifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".screens.MainActivity" />
```

You will then need to allow [Up](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#up) navigation by adding this to your `Activity`:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

For more information please see the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

Comment: This was introduced in 4.2. Please add instructions how to do it before that.

Answer (score 0):

that arrow is called an "up affordance".this page,

> http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

describes navigation patterns (i.e., how it's supposed to work, in comparison to the back button). the docs for `ActionBar` give details how to use it. e.g.,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)

the other answer here that suggests using the `parentActivityName` is clearly simpler, and a better approach if you are on the proper API level.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the drawable image of a white arrow as the actionbar item.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
or 
mActionBar = getActionBar(); (or getSupportActionBar())
mActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow);
```

there is a few inbuilt android back arrows you can use but you're best to find your own and add it to your drawable resource directories.